# Laravel 7.21 Class Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Laravel 7.21 Class Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input not found

I have take aliases in app.php but like

```
Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
```

Written in Controller like this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Access by like this

```
Input::all() , Input::get('name')
```

ANY CHANGES IN LARAVEL 7.21 version ???

Comment: I would appreciate if you could accept the answer please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#the-input-facade), since version `6.x` `Input` has been removed.

> The Input facade, which was primarily a duplicate of the Request
> facade, has been removed. If you are using the `Input::get` method, you
> should now call the `Request::input` method. All other calls to the
> Input facade may simply be updated to use the Request facade.